# Load Tree based xls using a Java API

Tags: apache-poi, jexcelapi

[image]
How to read a tree based xls using a Java API like Apache POI, etc. I want to read a xls which is in a tree based format i.e the data is grouped.

Comment: What happens if you just try to read it as normal?

Comment: I want that xls to be treated as a tree.

Comment: It'd probably be best to post a small screenshot of some of the data you have, then describe the kind of Java datastructure you want, and finally what steps you've take so far to generate that

Comment: @Gagravarr: Can you reply back now?

Comment: I'm still not seeing what's special about your case? Just read it by row, use the indent level in column A to decide when to nest, pop into your favourite tree-based datastructure in Java, job done!